# Error: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed

Tags: java, android

i'm new to Android programming, and I have an error,can anybody help me and explain why i have the Error:The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed? Here is my code. Thank you very much

```
<color name="puzzle_background">#ffe6f0ff </color>
<color name="puzzle_hilite">#ffffffff</color>
<color name="puzzle_light">#64c6d4ef</color>
<color name="puzzle_dark">#6456648f</color>
<color name="puzzle_foreground">#ff000000</color>
<color name="puzzle_hint_0">#64ff0000</color>
<color name="puzzle_hint_1">#6400ff80</color>
<color name="puzzle_hint_2">#2000ff80</color>
<color name="puzzle_selected">#64ff8000</color>
```

Comment: You don't have a root element, if that's your entire code

Comment: please post the full xml..

Comment: it's full code, i just missed the tags <resources>...</resources>

Comment: and one more question, R.strings.no_moves_label - what is it's directory, or what means the R. ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XML documents only one element can be at the top level.

Wikipedia: [Root element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_element)

Wrap your colors into something like :

```
<colors>
    <color name="puzzle_background">#ffe6f0ff </color>
    <color name="puzzle_hilite">#ffffffff</color>
    <color name="puzzle_light">#64c6d4ef</color>
    <color name="puzzle_dark">#6456648f</color>
    <color name="puzzle_foreground">#ff000000</color>
    <color name="puzzle_hint_0">#64ff0000</color>
    <color name="puzzle_hint_1">#6400ff80</color>
    <color name="puzzle_hint_2">#2000ff80</color>
    <color name="puzzle_selected">#64ff8000</color>
</colors>
```